# Android how to publish beta version of App

Tags: android, google-play

How do I upload the beta version of the app .. In developer console we have 3 categories to upload , one Alpha testing and second is  Beta testing and 3rd is production I have to publish beta version of the app. what should I do? Should I go to upload APK in Beta segment and promote that to APK or something else please remember I am asking about the beta release of the APP not beta testing?

Comment: just see this link. its useful to you..[Stack Link Related Beta Version App][1]
    


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401964/how-to-create-a-beta-for-my-android-app

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apps that are published as Beta are **not listed in the Play-Store!**

If you want someone to test it, you need to invite them (via G+) and send them an Opt-In-Link.

If you want to promote your App, just publish it normally and mention that it´s still in Beta.

EDIT: You can still promote an App that is in Beta to "normal" (production I think), no need to reupload or anything.

Comment: Need a little more clarification.Is there ll be any option (like drop down or something else) to mention that it is beta version ? or we have to mention it in the description. and second thing is for Beta release we have to upload APK in BETA TESTING segment or in PRODUCTION segment?

Comment: If it´s in (official) beta, you dont see in in the Play-Store - publish it as Beta testing if you want this. If you want to publish it as production, there is no way to mark it as beta, but you can write it in the description, like I did with my app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avitus.firstflight)

Comment: Thanks @Bejnamin ... Yes I want to publish it as a beta so that it will show in play store as a beta version. So what I get from your answer is I have to upload my APK in BETA Testing segment and from there I should promote it to production by this a Beta version ll be available on Google with a beta mark on APP. Correct?

Comment: No, not quite - On Google Play you CAN NOT publish an App as Beta on the Store - it´s always marked as "normal" app. You can only tell users that it´s in beta in the description/images.
So I´d recommend you just publish it normally, but write something like "xy is still in Beta" into your description. Remember, if you publish as Beta, it´s not in the Store, only if you publish it normally.

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb Will the downloads count remain the same when changing from BETA publish to NORMAL production publish? Or is it treated like a new app?

Comment: @pblead26 It should keep the download count, but I can´t say for sure.

Comment: My app is released in play store and I need to release the new version of app to beta by deactivating the released app and allow user to download only the beta version how is it possible? @BenjaminSchwalb

Answer (score 2):

The previous reply is a little bit outdated (10 years), so here's an updated information:

see here for early access release:

[Playstore : How to release early access app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430165/playstore-how-to-release-early-access-app)

and here the direct information from the Google:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases?hl=en

**Basically you have these options:**

- Draft
- Close testing (Alpha) - only users who knows about the app, no review required
- Open testing (Beta) - early access, requires review
- Production - before review
- Released/To-be-fixed - after review

Here is the scheme from the Google page:

[image: https://developers.google.com/static/assistant/console/images/release/release-001.png]

Comment: That Google link seems to be specific to "Actions" for Google Assistant, not apps?

Comment: It works for apps, verified