# Playstore : How to release early access app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I want to make an early release for my app but I dont have the option to select "Early Access" in playstore store listing section. How do I make my app come in early access part of playstore app ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I understand ["Recruit beta testers on Early Access"](https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/startups.html#be-part-of-early-access), these apps are beta versions. So you have to create a **public beta test** and add your APK. Then it should show up as "early access" version.

> To help you in the early stages of development, Early Access offers a showcase on Google Play for selected new apps still in beta testing.

Comment: Yes, as the above answer says for *Early Access*, you need to release your App in *Public Beta* also known as *Open Beta*.

Comment: Checkout this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en Few points to take care of :- 1. When creating the open beta release, do not specify any number of test users (to make App available to all users), 2. Do not push your App to production (I did it accidentally then I had no option), 3. Go to Google Play Console->Release Management->App Releases-> Open Track ->Create or Manage.

Comment: does one need to give privacy policy and license information and an about page with license and privacy policy inside the app when releasing in public beta? (i am asking this question also because no data leaves the device but i use location permission do i need to make a privacy policy and do all the work i stated above)?

Comment: @AshutoshChamoli i accidentally pushed my app to production. How do i disable that release?

Comment: Hey @RichardMuvirimi, When I posted the comment it was long back almost 3 years back, I was working as an Android dev. I am not sure if things may have changed now. At that time, once the app goes to production, you can't do much rather to just remove the app and change your package name & launch a new app in beta.

Comment: @AshutoshChamoli Thanks, figured it's not possible. One has to live with it