# Publish game on console with early access

Tags: google-play

I want to publish my google play game in early access mode. How can i submit.publish google play console game in early access mode?

Comment: Google Play is for Android software, I don't think you'd be able to publish console games on there, unless I'm misunderstanding part of your question. This question is also not directly programming related and also tagged with the wrong tag, so it will be closed down most likely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playstore : How to release early access app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430165/playstore-how-to-release-early-access-app)